# Equivalent of grep -C in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any function in pandas (or a way to simulate it) which does the same thing as

`cat fileName | grep -C 10 pattern > anotherFile`

would do on unix apart from writing code which would loop thoough the entire file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pandas analogue for `grep -C 2 "a"`:

```
In [342]: df
Out[342]:
   txt
0    q
1    f
2    i
3    t
4    y
5    n
6    r
7    o
8    f
9    g
10   m
11   s
12   f
13   o
14   v
15   e
16   s
17   a
18   n
19   h
20   w
21   q
22   a
23   i
24   a
25   s
26   l
27   e
28   l
29   f

In [343]: pattern = 'a'

In [344]: N = 2

In [345]: idx = df[df.txt.str.contains(pattern)].index

In [346]: filtered_idx = sorted(list(set([x for tup in zip(idx-N, idx+N) for x in range(tup[0], tup[1]+1)])))

In [347]: df.loc[filtered_idx]
Out[347]:
   txt
15   e
16   s
17   a
18   n
19   h
20   w
21   q
22   a
23   i
24   a
25   s
26   l
```

check with `grep -C`:

```
{ temp }  » grep -n -C 2 'a' aaa.txt                                                                          /d/temp
16-e
17-s
18:a
19-n
20-h
21-w
22-q
23:a
24-i
25:a
26-s
27-l
```

NOTE: that `grep` counts lines starting from `1`, pandas starts from `0` - that's why `grep`'s line numbers are always `one line ahead` compared to pandas index

setup:

```
import string
data = list(string.ascii_lowercase) * 2
df = pd.DataFrame({'txt': np.random.choice(data, 30)})
```

Comment: @nimbus3000, always glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

```
import pandas as pd

def cat_grep_direct(input, pattern, output):
    df = pd.read_csv(input, header=None, delimeter='obn0x1u5')
    df = df.loc[df.loc[:, 0].str.contains(pattern, regex=True), :]
    df.head(10).to_csv(output, index=None, columns=None)
```

Comment: what about an analogue for `-C 10` ?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I added `.head(10)` on the last `df`

Comment: It's not quite the same as `grep -C`. `grep -C 3` - should show all matched rows including 3 rows before and 3 rows after each match (without duplicates).